ExtrapolationHandler near miss
I want to use the undocumented option ExtrapolationHandler of InterpolatingFunction to set the value outside the range.  Here's a toy example showing my problem.
The following works as expected:
if = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 10^-3, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
(* InterpolatingFunction[<0.001, 6.2>] *)

if[0]
(* Indeterminate *)

However if the extrapolated point is just outside the range, ExtrapolationHandler lets me down:
if = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 10^-6, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}]
(* InterpolatingFunction[<1.*10^-6, 6.2>] *)

if[0]
(* -2.98938*10^-11 *)

Is there any quick fix to make ExtrapolationHandler more precise?  I'd rather not have to wrap if in another function like suggested here.

I think there is not much you can do about this, besides an if statement. There is an hard coded perturbation: perturb = (right-left)*.000005; and a point is considered inside if ((x >= (left-perturb)) && (x <= (right+perturb))). You might want to file a suggestion for this to be changed to be settable; but I am not sure when and if someone will be able to address this.

@user21 Thanks for the scoop!
